# Match to a default token when none of the specified match

Tags: java, default, match, token, antlr3

I want to match a list of well known identifiers and if there's no well known identifier I want it to become something like a default token. It would be something like:

TOKEN1: 'Token1'
                ;

TOKEN2: 'Token2'
                ;

DEFAULT: NONE OF THE ABOVE AND MUST FOLLOW LETTER (LETTER|NUMBER)*;

Anyone know if it's possible to accomplish that?

Regards,

Rui

Comment: this is a candidate for rule, not for token, so you can define `DEFAULT` as `LETTER (LETTER|NUMBER)*` and then define rule `tokensOrDefault` that is something like `(TOKEN1 | TOKEN2 | DEFAULT)`

Comment: Asked here too: http://antlr.markmail.org/message/wc5mzjjbi3mobea5